# Is an empty string a valid JSON key?

Tags: javascript, json

Is a JSON object having an empty string as a key valid, for example `{ "c": "x", "": "y" }`?

It certainly seems to be, or at least it doesn't seem to break the web if I using it in a browser as per [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9ogfebk/) having the following code:

```js
var a = { "a": "x", "b": "y" };
var b = { "c": "x", "": "y" };
var c = JSON.stringify(a);
var d = JSON.stringify(b);
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
var e = JSON.parse(c);
var f = JSON.parse(d);
console.log(e);
console.log(f);
```

There is a good reason why I need (want) to use an empty string for a key, but am I just asking for trouble, in terms of browser compatibility and future-proofing?

Comment: An empty string is a string. Of course you can only have one empty string property name in a given object.

Comment: A thing to consider is whether reconstituted JSON in a language other than JavaScript is going to be so tolerant. If your world is all JavaScript then that's not a problem of course.

Comment: if it works on IE, it will work everywhere xD

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Tl;dr Yes it is.

---

The [ECMA spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) states (highlighting is mine not the specs):

> ### 6 Objects
>
> .....
>
> The JSON syntax **does not impose any restrictions on the strings used
> as names**, does not require that name strings be unique, and does not
> assign any significance to the ordering of name/value pairs.

The section on how a string is formatted also allows you to go directly from `"` to the closing `"`:

> ### 9 String
>
> [image]